# Hardcoded FLUTTER_ROOT in Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Tags: xcode, flutter

I have a Flutter project which was created on one machine, pushed to GitHub and then pulled to another machine. The project couldn't be built on the second machine because the directory for `FLUTTER_ROOT` referenced in `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` is an absolute path from the first machine (`/Users/user1/flutter`).

In order to build the project on the second machine, I need to change the path in XCode to `/Users/user2/development/flutter`.

The `.gitignore` file used is the one that IntelliJ auto created for a brand new Flutter project, and it obviously doesn't ignore `ios/Runner.xcodeproj`.

I'm no expert, but I guess this file contains a lot of configurations one would want to keep in the repo, so ignoring it is not an option? What would be the best way to work around the issue of having different paths to the `flutter` directory on the two machines and still be able to work on the same remote Github repo?

Comment: It's a great question. Shame nobody could answer it :-(

Answer (score 0):

Flutter root should be added in your terminal profile file
~/.zshrc or ~/.bash_profile instead of user defined in ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file.

So in your ~/.zshrc file, add export flutter root path like this

```
# flutter root
export PATH="/Users/user1/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```